# Would you tell me which answer is correct?

Tags: interrogatives

It is only a question which, for instance, my friend is asking me, and I would like to know which one is not right. A few answer choices are available against each question. Please let me now which ones are not correct, and also please provide necessary explanation, so that it would be helpful for an English learner.

> **Question :**  Will you be travelling with children?
>
> **Answer 1:** Yes. I will be travelling with them.
>
> **Answer 2:** Yes. I will be doing so.
>
> **Answer 3:** Yes. I will be.

........

A few answer choices using **"so"**. Please also state that which of the following answers are wrong, with explanation.

> **Answer 4:** Yes. So will I be .
>
> **Answer 5:** Yes. So will I be doing.

.....

Is there any difference between these answers?

> **Question 2:** Will you travel with your children?
>
> **Answer 2a:** Yes, I will do so.
>
> **Answer 2b:** Yes ,so will I.

Comment: Please give us more context, what you want to say. What all home work you have done to learn it. And also please choose a proper title, that will go with the question you ask.

Comment: I have edited your questions, only to make it more understandable. Hope it will save the question from closing. @StoneyB gave a nice explanation. Go over his answer all over again if you haven't understood it already. Summary of his answer - answer 1,2,3 are correct. answer 4,5 wrong. answer 2a correct, answer 2b is wrong. For explanation read his answer again.

Answer (score 1):

Your *will* versions are all acceptable. So are

> Yes, I will.
> Yes.

But none of the *so* versions has this meaning. *So* at the **beginning** of a sentence, with subject/auxiliary inversion, means *also*; it  is used only to respond to a previous  positive statement.

> A: I am cold.
> B: So am I.  *means “I, too, am cold.”*
>
> B: John is cold. So am I. *means “I, too, am cold”.
>
> A: I will be traveling with my children.
> B: So will I. *means “I, too, will be traveling with my children.”*

*Do so* must be kept together, in that order, if you want the phrase to act as a 'pro-VP', having the force of a repetition of a previous VP.

> A: Will you travel with your children?
> B: Yes, I will **do so**.

Note that *do so* is rare and quite formal as an answer to a question. Most people will say simply *Yes* or *Yes I will*.

Comment: Are these correct? Yes. So will I be .

Yes. So will I be doing.

Comment: @nima_persian. Yes, if you mean "Yes, [like you,] I will be taking my children, too." (But most people will say just "So will I" or "Me, too." No, if you mean to respond to the question "Yes, I will be taking my children."

Comment: I am now too confused to understand

Comment: Do you eat sth? Yes I do. So, why 4,5 and 2b are not right?

Comment: @Nima_persion. As I say above, *So do I* is not used as the answer to a question but as an addition to a positive statement: A:"I eat bananas." B:"So do I." (= I do, too). *So* is used in an answer only after *do*, and it is very rare and formal there: A:"Do you eat bananas?" B:"Yes, I do (so)."